# Electric field operator in 2D geomatry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, plane-wave

In the free field (3D), transverse electric field operator is given by the below expression;

$$e^{\bot}(\textbf{R}) =i \sum_{\textbf{p},\lambda}\Big( \frac{\hbar cp}{2V\epsilon_{0}}\Big)^{1/2} \{e^{(\lambda)}(\textbf{p})a^{(\lambda)}(\textbf{p})e^{i\textbf{p.R}}-\bar{e}^{(\lambda)}(\textbf{p})a^{\prime(\lambda)}(\textbf{p})e^{-i\textbf{p.R}}\}
$$
here $\textbf{p}$=photon wave vector, p=corresponding wave number,$\textbf{R}$=position vector,$\lambda$=polarization vector,$a^{(\lambda)}(\textbf{p}),a^{\prime(\lambda)}(\textbf{p})$=photon annihilation and creation operators.
Also we know that plane wave expansion in cylindrical coordinates is given by, $H(pR)e^{in\alpha}$.

My issue is on finding electric field operator in 2D realm. Can I replace $e^{i\textbf{p.R}}$ of 3D by $H(pR)e^{in\alpha}$ of 2D and use above expression?